# Why my divs dont want to be in one line?

Tags: html, css

Im bothering with simple problem, just dont know why my divs dont want to be displayed in one line. Every thing should be fine, i use float: left.

This is how its looks like:

[image]

html:

```
  <div id="centrumwspolpraca">
    <div id="w1">Wspólne projekty przechodzą cały proces,<br>zaczynając od briefu po realizację i strategię marketingową.<div>
    <div id="w2"><img src="images/wspolpraca.png"><div>
    <div id="w3"><b class="regular">MYŚLIMY GLOBALNIE<div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
#centrumwspolpraca{
width:1200px;
height: 500px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
background: green;
}

#w1{
float:left;
width: 300px;
height: 500px;
overflow: hidden;
font-size: 12px;
position: relative;
background: red;
}
#w2{
float:left;
width: 800px;
height: 500px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
background: yellow;
}

#w3{
float:left;
width: 100px;
height: 500px;
overflow: hidden;
font-size: 12px;
position: relative;
background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not closing in the right way your `<div>` tags, you have:

```
<div id="w2"><img src="images/wspolpraca.png"><div>
```

It must be : Add the `/` to close the tag

```
<div id="w2"><img src="images/wspolpraca.png"></div>
```

The demo **http://jsfiddle.net/rc56k/2/**

Comment: OMG, just found it .. Thx, such a shame :D

Comment: Np mate glad to help you

Comment: @Lethysek if this answer was helpfull don't forget to make this the final check

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your HTML

```
<div id="centrumwspolpraca">
    <div id="w1">Wspólne projekty przechodzą cały proces,<br>zaczynając od briefu po realizację i strategię marketingową.</div>
    <div id="w2"><img src="images/wspolpraca.png"></div>
    <div id="w3"><b class="regular">MYŚLIMY GLOBALNIE</div>
</div>
```

close inner DIV's